# click on a link based on a specific td value in selenium

Tags: selenium

This is the source :

```
<tr style="">
    <td class="lrml">
       <div class="lrmnw">
        <a class="nclk" onclick="hashNavigate(1132763013,true,'\x26rdrctGoBack\x3dY\x26Id\x3dACOA\x2dDA5MG');"    href="javascript:void(0)">Restore</a>
          </div>
         </td>
      <td/>
    <td>Account</td>
   <td>TestDelete</td>
<td>4/30/2014 02:39 AM</td>
```

I want to be able to click on "restore" based on the `td` value "TestDelete". I have been struggling with this without any successful output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the XPath `//td[text()='TestDelete']/preceding-sibling::td//a[text()='Restore']`. It is more precise, and actually describes exactly what you said.

Comment: Thnx so much tht did wrk for me .. :) !!

Answer (score 0):

Following xpath worked for me: 
`//td[text()='TestDelete']//parent::tr//a[text()='Restore']`

Answer (score -1):

Better to use a `CSS` selector

```
css=a.nclk
```

Or:

```
css=a:contains('Restore')
```

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. `contains` is not part of the CSS selector standard and actually is usually from jQuery, or rather Sizzle which is the CSS selector engine that backs jQuery.